# Is anti-gravity technology available in Shadowrun?

Tags: lore, shadowrun

**Is anti-gravity *technology* available in the world of Shadowrun?**

If so, how widespread is its use, and which official source books and/or novels deal with it?

Official sources only, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is **No**.

There is no anti-gravity technology available that would not be available in the real world today. Obviously, shadowrun technology is more advanced and cheaper, so owning a helicopter, VTOL vehicle, hoovercraft or maglev train is not out of the question, but there was no technological breakthrough in that direction.

Magic can make things levitate and fly, but that's not exactly technology.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as of late in 5th edition.  The book you are looking for is Street Lethal (Pg 58-66).  It's experimental high end corporate technology, and is generally not for player use, outside of short term exposure or the occasional test use or target of a run.